# How to upgrade a unmanged package in salesforce

Tags: package

How to upgrade a unmanaged package in salesforce.When I have create a new version of application. but is shows me an error the unmanaged package "Dissapp" is already installed.you will need to uninstall it before its installing a new version.????

Answer (score 4):

Unmanaged package cannot be upgraded .You will have to create a managed version for your application to make it upgradeable.

For unmanaged package the installer has to uninstall the app each time you provide him your package .

Answer (score 2):

Unmanaged package can not be upgraded. Only managed packages can.

For managed packages, you have to uninstall and then install the updated package.

If you do not want to unistall the current package, what you can do is:

- Get the updated component files for the unmanaged package
- Use ANT Migration tool to upload the components